# Send a data to resources method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I need to send a data to methods resources route

Example:

```
Route::get('post/{post_type}', 'PostController@index')->where('post_type', '[A-Za-z]+');
```

But I do not know how to make it in resources route

```
Route::resource('post', 'PostController');
```

And when sending the data with the link

```
{{route('post.index',['post_type'=>'news'])}}
```

What is displayed in URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/post?post_type=news
```

But what I need:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/post/news
```

My attempt to solve this question :

```
Route::resource('post', 'PostController',['parameters'=>['post'=>'post_type']]);
```

But this only changes URL resources:

From : `admin/post`

to   :`admin/post_type`

I also have trouble getting this data in the index method:

To do this, I have acted:

```
public function index($post_type)
    { 
        return $post_type;
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge of `Resource Controllers`, you get only `` 7 fixed URI`s `` to work with around your resource.

So if you are calling `index` method, it has standard URI `/post`. You can not change it to `/post/anything`.

You should use pluralized version of resource in URI `posts`.
`Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');`

So you can not access `index` method from `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/post/news` url.

Comment: It means that I should not use resource Controller ?

Comment: @saeidyaghoobi You can but you have use prefined URIs to access predefined resource methods. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: This data should be send to all methods. What is the solution?

Comment: @saeidyaghoobi is it constant data, That is getting shared with all methods

Comment: I use 'post_type' to sort posts for both display and creation Like custom post_type in wordpress